# How can I convert a string in the format "YYYYMM" to "MMMYY"?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, date-conversion

I want to pass values in YYYYMM format such as "201509" to a function and retrieve the human-friendlier "MMMYY" format, such as "Sep 2015".

I thought this might work:

```
internal static string GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(String YYYYMMVal)
{
    string intermediateStr = YYYYMMVal + "01";
    DateTime intermediateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(intermediateStr);
    return intermediateDate.ToString("MMMyy");
}
```

...but no, it crashes with "*String was not recognized as a valid DateTime*"

ISTM that the YYYYMMDD format should be grokkable and convertible to a DateTime. What do I need to change?

### UPDATE

Since I wasn't getting quite what I wanted, I decided to "brute force it" like so:

```
internal static string GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(String YYYYMMVal)
{
    string yearAsTwoChars = YYYYMMVal.Substring(2, 2);
    string threeCharAbbreviation = YYYYMMVal.Substring(4, 2);
    if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("01"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Jan";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("02"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Feb";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("03"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Mar";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("04"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Apr";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("05"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "May";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("06"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Jun";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("07"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Jul";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("08"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Aug";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("09"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Sep";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("10"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Oct";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("11"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Nov";
    }
    else if (threeCharAbbreviation.Equals("12"))
    {
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Dec";
    }
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", threeCharAbbreviation, yearAsTwoChars);
}
```

...and, though it returns what I want "Sep 15", "Oct 15" etc., I still see "15-Sep" and "Oct-15" on my page...?!?

I'm calling that helper method like so:

```
var monthYearCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[_lastRowAddedPivotTableData + 1, 4];
monthYearCell.Value2 = ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(MonthYear);
```

I reckon Excel must be "autocorrecting" behind the scenes or something; reminds me of a movie I saw ("Reds" maybe?) where the protagonist went semi-ballistic when his editor changed what he wrote. I often feel this way about Word and Excel. How can I tell Excel (assuming this is the problem) to just leave it alone - "What I have written, I have written"?

Comment: Just use `DateTime.ParseExact` so you can tell it the exact format.

Comment: Or use DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: Care to weigh in?  Just curious: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336300/why-did-this-user-lose-all-his-rep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx). So your code will look like this:

```
internal static string GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(String YYYYMMVal)
{
    DateTime intermediateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(YYYYMMVal, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return intermediateDate.ToString("MMMyy");
}
```

Comment: This is good enough for now, as it returns "15-Sep" etc.; what the user may eventually demand (to retain the same format as currently used) is "Sep 15" etc.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I just tested it and it returns Sep15 as expected if you want space between the month and the year just change the ToString format to "MMM yy"

Comment: Strange; I get "15-Sep" and "15-Oct"... Even adding the space I get the same thing...

Comment: I got the answer on how to solves this problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048382/why-is-excel-changing-my-date-display-value-and-how-can-i-prevent-it-from-doing

Answer (score 1):

You could use `switch-case` instead of all those `if-else` blocks which would, imho, increase the readability. i.e.

```
switch (threeCharAbbreviation)
{
    case "01":
        threeCharAbbreviation = "Jan";
        break;
    case "02":
        //Etc.
    default:
        break;
}
```

And you can explicitly set format of cells in Excel. Haven't tested it myself but you can try the sample code below:

```
Excel.Range formatRange;
formatRange = xlWorkSheet.Range["A3", "B4"];
formatRange.NumberFormat = "MM-YY";
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(intermediateDate.ToString(), "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

Comment: should be parsing `YYYYMMVal`, not `intermediateDate.ToString()`.  OP want to return a `string`, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: if you look at the OP code, you will see that the parameter that is being passed in is being modified which is why its the intermediateDate that is being parsed

Comment: `intermediateDate` is the thing that the OP needs to populate with the parsing.  You meant to use `intermediateStr` and then you'd need to include the day portion in the format for it to work, where as the format you current have should work with `YYYYMMVal` instead, and no need for `intermediateStr`.

Comment: my bad, didnt see that