# Why is Excel changing my date display value, and how can I prevent it from doing that?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, date-formatting

It seems that Excel is taking values I assign to cells, such as "Sep 15" and changing them to "15-Sep"

I have code that should assign the val in the format I want (`MMM yy`):

```
internal static string GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(String YYYYMMVal)
{
    // code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045761/how-can-i-convert-a-string-in-the-format-yyyymm-to-mmmyy
    DateTime intermediateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(YYYYMMVal, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return intermediateDate.ToString("MMM yy");
}
```

...called like so:

```
var monthYearCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[_lastRowAddedPivotTableData + 1, 4];
monthYearCell.Value2 = GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(MonthYear);
```

...but the data is still being written/displayed as "YY-MMM", such as "15-Sep"

I debugged the value of `monthYearCell` after the two lines directly above execute, and find that the "Text" property of the monthYearCell object is indeed "15-Sep"; it "*should*" be "Sep 15", as that is what is being returned from the `GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM()` helper method.

Excel is obviously (right?) changing the values from "Sep 15" and such to "15-Sep" and such. I reckon Excel must be "autocorrecting" behind the scenes or something; it reminds me of a movie I saw once ("Reds" maybe?) where the protagonist went semi-ballistic when his editor changed what he wrote. I often feel this way about Word and Excel. How can I tell Excel (assuming this is the problem) to just leave it alone - "What I have written, I have written"?

I did try to change the value from the raw `"YYYYMM"` format to what I want this way previously:

```
monthField.NumberFormat = "MMM yy";
```

...but that changed values such as "201509" and "201510" to "Sep 51" for both...?!?

Comment: Set the cell format to Text before assigning the value, or prepend the value with ' to indicate to Excel it should be treated as text.

Comment: I tried:
monthYearCell.Format = "Text";
before assigning the value to the Value2 property and, although it compiled and ran, I got the runtime error: 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Format'

Comment: The second idea worked, though:
monthYearCell.Value2 = "'" + ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(MonthYear); Make that an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prepend the value with ' to indicate to Excel it should be treated as text then it will not try to parse your value into a Date.

Comment: You can add a similar answer for a 50-pt bounty here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050213/how-can-i-get-the-members-of-a-pivottable-column-field-to-display-in-natural-ord

Answer (score 1):

It will translate any string to dateTime when you set the Excel field with a date format.

use:

```
monthYearCell.NumberFormat = "@";
```

then use:

```
monthYearCell.Value = GetMMMYYFromYYYYMM(MonthYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from the way Excel stores dates. They are the number of days since 01-01-1900.  [Stored dates in Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm)

When extracting them, they are looking at your localized setting for the format. Any formatting you want to keep needs to be after or while retrieving them.

Comment: So after assigning the value as I want it to the object's text value, what need I do to prevent Excel from high-handedly taking over and "improving" on my work?

Comment: Why do you have 60 gold medals, 209  silver, and 424 bronze, and your total reputation is only 38?  How is that possible?  Anyway, there must be a data format applied in Excel.  Can you simply change it to General, or force it to be what you want?  Right-click the column, click Format > Custom > Type = 'mmm-yy'.  That should do it.