# How can I get the members of a PivotTable column field to display in natural order, rather than alphabetically?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-interop, date-formatting

I was taught how to convert a date-as-string value that was being converted from what I wanted ("Sep 2015", "Oct 2015" etc.) to what Excel thought it should be ("15-Sep", "15-Oct" etc.) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048382/why-is-excel-changing-my-date-display-value-and-how-can-i-prevent-it-from-doing).

When it was displaying "badly," the columns at least displayed in the right order ("2015-Sep" followed by "2015-Oct"). Now that they are "Sep 15" and "Oct 15", though, they are displaying out of "natural" order and in alphabetical order ("Oct 15" followed by "Sep 15").

This is the too-typical scenario (especially egregiously evident in software development) of the solving of one problem causing another one to rear its ugly rear.

This is how I create the "month" part of the PivotTable:

```
var monthField = pvt.PivotFields("MonthYr");
monthField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
```

Before fixing the display format problem:

[image]

After fixing the display format problem ("15-Sep" is now "Sep 15", etc., but the months are now out of order):

[image]

Can I "have my cake and eat it, too" so to speak? If so, how?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you may want to just change the "number formats" of the column label cells to the type you want "mmm yy" rather than converting the date into a string before creating your pivot table, which excel doesn't recognize as a date and tries to sort alphabetically.  Then you can have it sort in correct chronological order.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and it backfired on me:
monthField.NumberFormat = "MMM yy";<= This changed "201509" and "201510" to "Sep 51" for both

Comment: That's because the *values* _201509_ and _201510_ in excel correspond to _9/16/2451_ and _9/17/2451_.  Excel stores dates like a float, with integers representing days, and fractions representing time.  Try converting your string into a datevalue with _=DATE(year,month,day)_ or read this article on how to do it in VBA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227484(v=vs.60).aspx
You want to convert the data into real date data, otherwise excel won't understand how to sort chronologically.  You need to have it in date format before you build the pivot, then format the columns as desired.

Comment: For example, 42248 = 9/1/2015... while 42278 = 10/1/2015.

Comment: Thanks, but now I perceive with greater perception than previously why my coworker proclaims a hatred for Excel. BTW, I need to do this conversion in C#; I will get to it, eventually, I guess...

Comment: Excel can be a pain, but I love excel, you can do almost anything with it, and it's given me job security here, since everyone else goes to me for excel problems :)  

BTW, the issue you're facing is common... you want to display month/year and sort by it, but you should normally not worry about formatting/display/labels issue until after you do your analysis (building pivot table) work.  Since you converted them before building the pivot, excel doesn't know it's a date anymore.  but if you convert them as excel datetype, then you can configure how they display once you've built your table.

Comment: This might help with your C# issue:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx  
  
string date = "01/08/2008";  
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the comments, it sounds like you need to convert your C# date to an excel date.  In the second comment you mention that you were able to get values "201509" and "201510" onto an excel sheet.

I suggest you separate the year and month using the `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions, then use the `DATE()` function to get the Excel serial number for 9/1/15 and 10/1/15.

Here's a screenshot of the steps I'm think of (Happy Halloween!):

[image: Dates in Excel PivotTable Issue]

Finally, you can now format the Serial number using your formula `monthField.NumberFormat = "MMM yy"`.  Excel will realize this is a date and sort it chronologically.